# Resolving a Concrete Implemention of Interface Generically in Castle.Windsor

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection

I am using Castle.Windsor as a DI container and the thing that I want is resolving any implementation's concrete implementation. There are many interfaces and classes inside, and each class implements interfaces. In business layer, I want to resolve the concrete implementation. Here is the code section:

```
public static class BootStrapper
{
    //buradaki yapıları iyi bilmem gerekiyor. 
    private static IWindsorContainer _container = null;

    public static void RegisterAllInterfaces()
    {

        // 1. Instantiate the IWindsor container object
        _container = new WindsorContainer();

        // 2. Register the services and the respective components that implement them
        _container.Register(                   
            Component.For(typeof(IProductRepository)).ImplementedBy(typeof(ProductRepository))  
            Component.For(typeof(IShop)).ImplementedBy(typeof(Shop))  
            Component.For(typeof(IPayment)).ImplementedBy(typeof(Payment))  
            );

    }

    public static Service.Somut.ProductService GetDefaultProductService()
    {
        Service.Somut.ProductService sonuc = null;
        IProductRepository retriever = null;

        retriever = _container.Resolve<IProductRepository>();
        sonuc = new Service.Somut.ProductService((ProductService)retriever);

        return sonuc;
    }


    public static object GetConcreteImplementation(Type TypeToResolve)
    {
        var impl = _container.Resolve(TypeToResolve);

        return impl;

    }
}
```

I want to get the IProductRepository in run time. I am getting it as such:

```
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this._presenter = new ProductListPresenter(this, BootStrapper.GetDefaultProductService());

        this.ddlCustomerType.SelectedIndexChanged += delegate { _presenter.Display(); };
    }
```

I want to use GetConcreteImplementation and give the interface itself as a parameter. How can I do it? Thanks in advance.